# Redirect URL to a new server, fixing a new URL

Tags: apache, redirect, gunicorn

Structure:

http://192.168.123.123:80               (Apache)




http://192.168.123.123:8001/admin       (Gunicorn + Docker)

My Apache (it works):

ProxyPass               /admin          http://127.0.0.1:8001/admin




ProxyPassReverse        /admin          http://127.0.0.1:8001/admin

I need every redirect to Gunicorn, go with the URL NEW:

http://192.168.123.123/NEW/admin

I can redirect, but Django understands that NEW is his:

"The current path, NEW/admin, didn't match any of these"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8001/NEW/

ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8001/NEW/

RequestHeader set SCRIPT_NAME /NEW

RequestHeader set X-FORWARDED-PROTOCOL ssl

RequestHeader set X-FORWARDED-SSL on